# ASP.Net - Unable to change text of Label from a Delegate Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, raspberry-pi

Hi I'm trying to make a single .html page that displays out the readings of my Raspberry Pi in Real-Time.

The Data is being sent over which triggers the Delegate.

However, the function that the Delegate triggers isn't able to interact with any Control in my ASP.Net Page.

Here's how my code looks like:

```
public partial class newIndex : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        DataComms dataComms;

        public void commsDataReceive(string strData)
        {
            // This line is able to successfully print out the strData
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(strData);

            // This line doesn't throw an error but doesn't work
            Label1.Text = strData; 
        }

        private void InitComms()
        {
            dataComms = new DataComms();
            dataComms.dataReceiveEvent += new DataComms.DataReceivedDelegate(commsDataReceive);
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InitComms();
        }

    }
```

My theory is that after the Page loads I'm unable to make any changes to it dynamically?? So I can solve this using an UpdatePanel Right?

Well I tried that too and it didn't work also as I had to call `UpdatePanel1.Update()` which is accessing the control UpdatePanel.

If anyone could help I'll be so thankful!

Answer (score 0):

Server pages do not work in this way. Most likely page is already sent to browser by the time commsDataReceive is fired. I guess you have only one "client" to show this information so you can make dataComms as static and update code to follow. This is certainly not the best solution but should work for your requirement

```
public partial class newIndex : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
       static DataComms dataComms;
       static string lastData="";

        public void commsDataReceive(string strData)
        {
            // This line is able to successfully print out the strData
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(strData);

            // This line doesn't throw an error but doesn't work
            lastData = strData;
        }
 
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              if (dataComms != null)
              {
                 dataComms = new DataComms();
                 dataComms.dataReceiveEvent += new DataComms.DataReceivedDelegate(commsDataReceive);
              }

            Label1.Text = lastData; 
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply!  but doesn't this means i'll have to refresh the page in order to get the latest saved data? I wan't the label to update automatically without postback thats what i meant by `real-time`

Comment: in this case web sockets is what you are looking for. If you are using asp.net core then this can help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/websockets?view=aspnetcore-5.0